# SharePoint is Redirecting to Yammer because of yammer feed embed

Tags: sharepoint, yammer

I've embedded a yammer feed using the "embed this feed in Your Site" into my team SharePoint. When I'm already logged into yammer and navigate to my team SharePoint I am redirected to my yammer feed at Yammer.com. If I am logged out of yammer I can access my team SharePoint without being redirected. How do I stop this redirection if I'm already logged into Yammer? I'm using IE 11 and have added yammer.com, sharepoint.com, assets-yammer.com to my trusted sites.

Comment: This behavior seems to be intermittent because it is not redirecting today.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact issue. It appears that it may have been due to some kind of authentication mix-up. I was logged into my company network prior to signing in, but logged in as a user on another tenant with its own Yammer network. The issue went away immediately when I logged out of yammer and then logged back into the site.